# RXjs flatMap затем "объединить" его снова

Tags: angularjs, angular4, rxjs

Привет всем. Вопрос по Rx.js:

Есть любой Observable в моем случае это this.subject.asObservable()  но может быть любой другой this.dataService.get()
если на этот Observable поставить this.dataService.get().subscribe((data: Model[]) => (this.data = data));
то результатом будет:

[{…}, {…}, ….] - коллекция Model объктов

Что хочу просто отфильтровать данную коллецию в соответствии с определенный набором фильтров например age > 20 && …
и в subscribe получить уже отфильтрованную коллекция без лишних данных.

filter age > 20 я привел для примера понятно что они могу быть в 10 раз сложнее и с какими-то приведениями объектов к конкретному классу

Как я решил:

```
this.subscribers.models = this.service.get().pipe(
    map(items => (items.filter(item => item.age > 20))),
).subscribe((data: Model[]) => (this.data = data));
```

Что не нравиться:
Не нравиться то что внутри pipe map я использовал нативный js filter вместо Rx.js оператор filter

Думаю что должно быть что-то типа такого и важно не использовать функции нативного js  только Rx.js

```
this.subscribers.models = this.service.get().pipe(
      flatMap((item: any) => item),
      filter((item: any) => (item.age > 20)),
      reduce((acc: any, currentValue: any) => ([...acc,currentValue])]),
).subscribe((data: Model[]) => (this.data = data));
```

Но так правильно не работает
Коллекция разбивается flatMap, после этого корректно фильтруется но как ее собрать обратно в коллекцию я точно незнаю, попробовал reduce вроде должно работть но не работает.

Может кто с подобный встречался(Редовая задача практический для любого ajax в angular 2/4/5) нужно разбить flatMap потом собрать обратно.
Буду рад любой подсказке

Comment: _Но так правильно не работает_ - укажи начальное значение для reduce

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Код с `reduce` вполне рабочий, если исправить синтаксическую ошибку и указать начальное значение аккумулятора:

```
reduce((acc: any, currentValue: any) => [...acc,currentValue], []),
```

На выходе будет как раз собранный массив.

[**Пример Online**](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?js=%0ARx.Observable%0A%20%20.of%28%5B1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5%2C6%2C7%5D%29%0A%20%20.flatMap%28a%20%3D%3E%20a%29%0A%20%20.filter%28a%3D%3E%20a%20%3E%204%29%0A%20%20.reduce%28%28acc%2Cc%29%20%3D%3E%20%5B...acc%2Cc%5D%2C%20%5B%5D%29%0A%20%20.subscribe%28val%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28JSON.stringify%28val%29%29%29%0A)